# Modify plainnat.bst to underline contents of 'title' field

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Writing a book. Most of my references are academic articles, some of which have over a dozen authors. After playing with many different bibliography styles, using `natbib` with the `plainnat` style was the only one that I really liked *except* I want the contents of the `title` field underlined because with dozen+ authors, it can be hard when skimming the bibliography to see where the `author` field ends and the `title` field begins. I specifically do not want any italics because those can trigger dyslexia, but underline is usually okay.

In `plainnat.bst` I *think* the part I need to modify (in local copy obviously) is

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to modify that so that title gets underlined.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plainnat` bibliography style practices "sentence style" for the contents of the `title` field, meaning that all words in the `title` field, with the exception of the first word and items encased in curly braces, get converted to lowercase.

The preserve sentence style while also underlining the contents of the `title` fields -- not only for entries of type `@article`, but for all other entry types as well -- I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Copy the file `plainnat.bst` and rename the copy to, say, `plainnat-ul.bst`. (Don't modify a file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `plainnat-ul.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- After the function `emphasize`, insert a new function called `underline` as follows:

  ```
  FUNCTION {underline}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "\ul{" swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  ```
- Then, find the function `format.title`. In this function, change the line

  ```
      { title "t" change.case$ }
  ```

  to

  ```
      { title "t" change.case$ underline }
  ```

  to apply both the built-in function `change.case$` and the newly-created function `underline` to the contents of the `title` field.
- Save the file `plainnat-ul.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-ul}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% create a test bibliography "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="Anne Author",title="Lots of Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{soul} % for "\ul" macro
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-ul}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay I figured out something that works. It requires using the `soul` package because `\underline{}` doesn't wrap well.

I added the following function:

```
FUNCTION {underline}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\ul{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

(based on the `FUNCTION {emphasize}}

Then inside `FUNCTION {article}` I commented out line and added new:

```
%format.title "title" output.check
title underline "title" output.check
```

That at least does what I want for article case.

Comment: +1. Any reason for commenting out the instruction `format.title "title" output.check`, though?

Comment: No, I misunderstood what it does. I just uncommented it and rebuilt the book and it still does what I want so clearly I didn't need to comment it out. Thank you!

Comment: Strike that - when uncommented the title gets put in twice---once without underline and once with---so it does need to be commented out.